# Use the Django ORM in a standalone script (again)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to use the Django ORM in some standalone screen scraping scripts. I know this question has been asked before, but I'm unable to figure out a good solution for my particular problem.

I have a Django project with defined models. What I would like to do is use these models and the ORM in my scraping script. My directory structure is something like this:

```
project
    scrape
        #scraping scripts
        ...
        test.py
    web
        django_project
            settings.py
            ...
            #Django files
```

I tried doing the following in `project/scrape/test.py`:

```
print os.path.join(os.path.abspath('..'), 'web', 'django_project')
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath('..'), 'web', 'django_project'))
print sys.path
print "-------"
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'
#print os.environ
from django_project.myapp.models import MyModel
print MyModel.objects.count()
```

However, I get an `ImportError` when I try to run test.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django_project.myapp.models import MyModel
ImportError: No module named django_project.myapp.models
```

One solution I found around this problem is to create a symbolic link to `../web/govcheck` in the scrape folder:

```
:scrape rmanocha$ ln -s ../web/govcheck ./govcheck
```

With this, I can then run test.py just fine. However, this seems like a hack, and more importantly, is not very portable (I will have to create this symbolic link everywhere I run this code).

So, I was wondering if anyone has any better solutions for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it shouldn't be:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath('..'), 'web'))
```

Also, make sure there's an `__init__.py` file (empty is fine) in `project/web/django_project`.

P.S. I'd recommend feeding `os.path.join`'s output to `os.path.abspath` instead of the other way.

Answer (score 8):

Found an easy way to reuse existing django app's settings for console script:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ

import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from myapp.models import Object

for o in Object.objects.all():
    print o
```

Comment: Note that the setup_environ function has been deprecated as of Django 1.4. See the release notes at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#django-core-management-setup-environ

Comment: Besides, don't `import settings`. Do `from django.conf import settings`. This will properly locate the settings file even if it doesn't happen to be on the Python path.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is six years old but this alternative might appeal to someone searching this topic.  Assuming Django's `manage.py` is in `project/`, and assuming `main()` is the script's entrypoint, then let Django take the strain:

```
./manage.py shell -c 'from scrape.test import main; main()'
```