# Django import User independently

Tags: python, django

**I wrote the python file in an app dir, I wanted to get a user from my database by name, then do something independently in the script.**

**I tried the following:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.filter(username='xiaofei')
print user
```

but:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

**The final solution:**

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.abspath('..')))
import settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ
setup_environ(settings)

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.filter(username='xiaofei')
print user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [perform a few tasks manually](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/) when writing a standalone Django script.

Comment: I searched 'standalone Django script' and find an answer similar to your recommended blog, but the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444879/use-the-django-orm-in-a-standalone-script-again) really helpful after I moved my script to the settings' folder

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a custom management command if you plan on running this command more than once. It only requires a small amount of boilerplate code and a special directory within your app. It will solve your problem and help improve the long term maintainability of your project.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/